# iOS AppleHealth - Push data with or without taking care of what is already stored

Tags: ios, swift, applehealth

We have an app that tracks steps, distance, calories ... Now we want to push the data into Apple Health. The iPhone is tracking data by itself so I'm wondering if I should simply push the data we measured (which will be added to the existing data) or if I should calculate the difference
from existing data to our measured data and just add what's missing.

Example:

Apple measured 500 steps from 11-12 am. Our bracelet measured 800 steps. While the phone might have been lying somewhere and the bracelet has always been worn, I rely on the bracelet data. So do I push 800 steps or 300 steps ?

Many thanks,
Sven

Comment: What do you tests say? I don't use HealthKit a whole lot but Apple does some filtering to prevent duplicate workouts and doubling "active energy". Does Apple filter steps? You have to perform testing to identify how your apps info is affecting the user.

Comment: But that is the problem: I don't understand how this is meant to be. If I push what we measured without taking care of what apple had measured, it creates a sum and of both data sources, which is nor correct. On the other hand, you can see which data is pushed by which app and If I only push the difference, it looks like our app measured a correct value. But maybe I should ask in an apple forum.